# How to lookup a Map with keys of Array, without reference to the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I need to operate on a coordinate object like this:

```
type Pos = [number, number];
```

I want to make a Map from coordinates to string:

```
type Board = Map<Pos, string>

let a1 = [1,1]

let board = new Map([a1, 'a1']);
```

Now I can access `a1` like `board.get(a1)`.

But what if I generate `a1` like this `[1,1]` and look it up:

```
board.has([1,1]) // false, I want this to be true
```

Comment: Not so easily. You'll need to (1) retrieve all keys from the map (2) iterate through them to find which one matches the indicies you're looking for by using one of the linked methods

Comment: So it's not a good idea to use array as keys in javascript?

Comment: You can if you want, but if you won't have a reference to the created arrays later to look up values, it's probably not a good idea, since the logic you'll require will take quite a few lines for something that *should* be trivial. Consider a different data structure, like keys of `'1_1'` instead

Comment: But I need to operate on the individual numbers also test them for reference equality like case classes in scala